# ubuntu 13.10 doesn't boot up

Tags: 13.10

I have downloaded the ISO file and copied on a usb drive
I have made a live usb
I have changed the boot order
ubuntu loads but after loading system stucks on a blank screen(on both trying and installing)
md5sum has verified the hash key
What should I do now?

Comment: I had similar issues in the past and it was caused by the graphics driver. Can you tell us which video card you have?

Answer (score 1):

Try including nomodeset as a boot option in grub. From the main grub bootloader press 'e' to edit the boot parameters. Find where it reads:

`quiet splash`

Edit to look like this:

```
quiet splash nomodeset
```

Hopefully this will solve your boot issue. If so, try changing your graphics driver from the 'Additional Software' app.